# Error in calling ImageMagick from Matlab

Tags: matlab, system, imagemagick-convert

I have installed ImageMagick in my system (windows), and its commands are there in system PATH. Its working absolutely fine through Command line
I want to call the "convert" function of ImageMagick from Matlab using system command. 
'C:\Users\Vivek' is the Path to image. I have to test working of ImageMagick through Matlab, as i need it in further processing (Making input suitable to Tesseract OCR)

```
    cmd= ['convert ' 'C:\Users\Vivek\208.jpg ' 'C:\Users\Vivek\208.png']
    system(cmd);
```

It says Invalid Parameter - C:\Users\Vivek\208.png, I tried some other ways. But, all the time the problem is with the second parameters.

Need Help

Thanks

Comment: what is the current working directory in Matlab? is it the same as the one you use when running from command line?

Comment: If all you want is to convert from jpg to png, you can simply use `imread` and `imwrite` in matlab

Comment: I want to test ImageMgick, i have to use it in further processing of my work (making images suitable for Tesserac OCR).
I just checked the "copy' command, its working fine through Matlab.

 cmd= ['copy ' 'C:\Users\Vivek\209g.jpg ' 'C:\Users\Vivek\Desktop\209g.png'];
system(cmd);

the problem is in the way second parameter is being given. Not able to deduce it..

Comment: Have you tried to specify full path to convert? Maybe you have other convert executable somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows comes with its own `convert` program, and it looks like you're calling that one because it's first on the path in this context. It's described here on ImageMagick's site: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/#convert_issue

I do not have ImageMagick installed, and I get the same error message when I try calling convert. That's consistent with your code getting the wrong `convert` program.

```
C:\Users\janke>convert C:\Users\Vivek\286.jpg C:\Users\Vivek\208.png
Invalid Parameter - C:\Users\Vivek\208.png
```

Specify the full path to ImageMagick's `convert` program and it should work for you.

Comment: Thanks Andrew :) That was the problem only :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution mentioned in the last post is the *standard* way to solve the issue, but the *simplest* way to do this is to just rename the ImageMagick's `convert.exe` file to something else, like `convert1.exe`, and use this filename in your scripts.