# Calling Bash scripts from Matlab with W10 Linux subsystem?

Tags: bash, matlab, imagemagick

I am making routinely system calls from Matlab (R2016b on W10 64) to integrate some ImageMagick functions. Now I have just read about the existence of the W10 Linux subsystem. Is it possible to call with this option given Bash scripts from Matlab that implement themselves long ImageMagick processing pipelines? And if yes how?

Comment: I do not know Matlab. But these links may be of interest that found via a Google search. https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/27762-executing-unix-commands-set-in-path-in-matlab-does-not-work-with-unix-command. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15917023/error-in-calling-imagemagick-from-matlab. Also be careful that you do not confuse the Windows convert.exe with the ImageMagick convert.exe.

Comment: See also https://atchieu.wordpress.com/2012/04/08/adding-system-paths-tousing-external-unix-tools-from-the-matlab-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script from `Matlab` using `!<script>` or `system(<script>)`. See [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/362225-imagemagick-through-command-line) or [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Theory/Convolution_Integral/matlab) for  calling `convert` as an example.

Comment: as I wrote I call the Win binary IM convert (with full path) routinely from Matlab. The question is about calling Bash scripts from Matlab and those scripts are using IM

Answer (score 0):

With

```
bash -c "command"
```

one can access the Bash shell from the Command Prompt, PowerShell, or elsewhere in Windows so this could be the way to call a Bash script from Matlab [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/262086/how-to-run-linux-commands-from-outside-the-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) .